# How do I set the background color of a div with a variable?

Tags: html, rgb

I want to color a `div-box` on a `red` to `green` scale according to the value of the variable `box.benefit`. The variable `box.benefit` goes from `0` - `255`.

The problem is the `green` part, where I try to get the inverse by subtracting. Without the subtracting, it is working.

```
<div class= "draggable" id={{box.id}} 
  style="background-color:rgb({{ box.benefit }}, (255 - {{ box.benefit }}), 0); 
     width:{{box.cost}}px"></div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can not "do math" in css. An option would be to use javascript to do the math, i.e. calculate the rgb-value and set the style of the div. Where do you get the box.benefit value from?

Comment: I pass a field with several boxes from django.view. Then I create in a for loop the boxes which should be coloured according to their benefit

Comment: I tried to call a javascript function out of the style section and returned the inverse color, but the call isn't executed.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact that it is unclear to me from your post when or how the change in color is triggered and how you get the `box.benefit` value, I made this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsBx9/) to explain how this can be easily done with jQuery. The trigger is now simulated when the target `div` is clicked. The `'red'` value is now hardcoded but could be obtained dynamically if you explain where it is set.

The html and initial css are as follows

```
<div class="draggable" id="box.id">Target</div>​

.draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}​
```

And the javascript

```
$('.draggable').click(function(){
    var boxcost = "200px";
    var boxbenefit = 25;
    var green = 255-boxbenefit;
    var rgb = "rgb("+boxbenefit+", "+green+", 0)";
    var cssObj = {
      'background-color' : rgb,
      'width' : boxcost
    }
    $(this).css(cssObj);   
});​
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply. The color must be set right from the start though, not when the box is clicked!
The box.benefit comes from a variable I pass from django.view to the html template

Comment: Ok so in that case, if you are able to pass values to a view, you should just calculate the green value server side (just like you do with the box.benefit and box.cost) and pass that as `{{box.green}}`.

Comment: I would like to keep the numbers of variables within the box model to a minimum. Therefore I do not want to add a "green" variable to the box model since it does not carry any additional information

Answer (score 1):

the `style` attribute can't take an equation.  You'll need to compute the final value within the variable itself and then input that into your `rgb`.

I'm not well-versed with Ember.js, but it looks like you might be using it.  If you are, you might try something like this:

**Ember**

```
box = Ember.Object.create({
  benefit: 0,
  inverseColor: function() {
    return 255 - this.get('benefit');
  // Call this flag to mark the function as a property
  }.property()
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class= "draggable" id={{box.id}} 
  style="background-color:rgb({{ box.benefit }}, ({{ box.inverseColor }}), 0); 
     width:{{box.cost}}px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
I am not using Ember, I define the class "draggable" like this in my style section:

     .draggable {
  padding: 4px;
  margin:2px;
  border:2px outset rgb(237,237,237);
  background: #ffffff;
  float:left;
  height:20px;
  cursor:move;
  color: #000;
}

Can I somehow build in a function in there to calculate the Inverse?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `{{}}` notation.  What are you using?

Comment: I use text/css, draggable is a class

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do calculations and use variables in CSS using [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) also known as "Sassy CSS".

This is a sample example from their webpage:

```
$blue: #3bbfce;
$margin: 16px;

.content-navigation {
  border-color: $blue;
  color:
    darken($blue, 9%);
}

.border {
  padding: $margin / 2;
  margin: $margin / 2;
  border-color: $blue;
}
```

There are other features that make it very nice for use.Also, it is automatically embedded in "Ruby on Rails".